# Handsontable in Handsontable Dropdown Height Adjustment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, handsontable

How to allow fixed height in this dropdown menu? (Column Car)

I have been fiddling endlessly to fix the height issue. I want a fixed height dropdown menu max 300px. I have used [AutoRowSize](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/5.0.0/AutoRowSize.html) height feature and other height features within the handsontable site, but none seem to have worked.

I have run out of ideas. Any suggestions or alternatives I can try?

I am using **Handsontable in Handsontable** feature ([Found Here](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/5.0.0/demo-handsontable.html)).

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/72dgoLva/3/

```
    columns: [
  {
    type: 'handsontable',
    handsontable: {
      colHeaders: ['Marque', 'Country', 'Parent company'],
      autoColumnSize: true,
      data: manufacturerData,
      getValue: function() {
        var selection = this.getSelectedLast();

        // Get always manufacture name of clicked row
        return this.getSourceDataAtRow(selection[0]).name;
      },
    }
  },
  {type: 'numeric'}

]
```

[image: How to apply scroll?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.handsontableEditor .ht_master {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
}
.handsontableEditor .ht_clone_top {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

... seems to do the job. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/72dgoLva/29/).

I had to use `!important` to override inline styles placed by HoT on elements, on the fly. To limit the chances of this affecting other instances, prefix selectors with a specific identifier for this instance.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.